# C LINUX\WINSOCK- check FIN packet in Send

Tags: c, linux, sockets, winsock, send

I am trying to understand how to avoid the following scenario:

1. A client kills its process. A FIN message is sent to server.
2. Server receives the FIN message from the client.
3. A milisecond after the server receives the FIN message, the server uses the send message, and sends information to the client.

Using the C API- can the server know what packets are acknowledged by the client?

If so- what are the commands in Linux\Winsock?

Comment: Can you tell us more abot th problem you want to solve? It could help in finding alternate solutions.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the scenario you describe. An incoming FIN only means that the sender has stopped sending. It could still be receiving. Only a send, or several, can tell. I don't see what ACKs have to do with it. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question comes up periodically. Short answer: The TCP layer in the OS intentionally **does not** pass up "acks" (acknowledgement of receipt) to the application layer.  And if it did, it would be the rope you would hang yourself by.  While TCP is considered "reliable", it doesn't actually have a way to indicate if the application code above it has actually *processed* the received bytes.

You mentioned "packets", but that is a very ambiguous term.  Your socket application may have the notion of "messages" (not packets), but TCP does not have the concept of a packet or even a message. It sends byte "streams" that originate from your application code. TCP segmentation, IP fragmentation, and other factors will split your message up into multiple packets on the wire. And TCP has no knowledge of what IP packets make up the entire application message. (Common socket fallacy - many developers erroneously believe a "send" corresponds to an identically sized "recv" on the other side).

So the only code that can acknowledge success receipt of a message is the socket application itself. In other words, your client/server protocol should have its own system of acknowledgements.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Linux, but under Windows if a process is killed with established connections open, those connections are forcibly (hard) reset. The peer will receive a RST, not a FIN, and further communication over the connection is impossible.